# Subsheaf of a torsion-free sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a noetherian projective scheme, $\mathcal{F}$ a torsion-free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module on $X$ and $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ submodule. Is it possible that $\mathcal{G}$ is torsion-free?

Comment: These are sheaves of what? $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules? Or just abelian groups?

Comment: @hunter: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed $\mathcal{G}$ is always torsion-free. Let $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ and suppose $s \in \mathcal{G}(U)$ is such that $fs = 0$. Then $fs = 0$ in $\mathcal{F}(U)$, and hence $s = 0$ in $\mathcal{F}(U)$ which is assumed torsion-free. Since $\mathcal{G}(U) \to \mathcal{F}(U)$ is an injective map of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-modules, we conclude that $s = 0$.